# God promised never to do an event such as the flooding ever again. How can judgement day happen then?

Tags: bible, noah

God promised never to do an event such as the flooding ever again. How can judgement day happen then?

Wouldn't that break the promise?

Comment: Hi and welcome, if you haven't already done so, please take the [tour](http://christianity.stackexchange.com/tour) and browse the [help centre](http://christianity.stackexchange.com/help) to help you come to grips with how this site works.

Comment: The promise was not to never again judge through "something like a flood", it was precisely not to judge through a worldwide flood again. Other things aren't in question.

Comment: Probably reread the relevant verses. Then see if your question makes sense. Genesis 8 and 9.

Comment: Please read best answer below.

I wanted to make sure it was flood specific (just seems strange of all the ways to do it the significance of saying not a flood but anything else). Read the conversation below if interested.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The promise was specific to **flooding**:

> 11 I establish my covenant with you: Never again will all life be destroyed by the waters of a flood; never again will there be a flood to destroy the earth.” - [Genesis 9:11 NIV](https://www.biblegateway.com/passage/?search=gen%209%3A11&version=NIV)

Your interpretation of this as 'an event like flooding' is not warranted by the text and is contradicted by other scriptures that *do* talk of how God will conclude his final judgment, eg:

> 3 Above all, you must understand that in the last days scoffers will come, scoffing and following their own evil desires. 4 They will say, “Where is this ‘coming’ he promised? Ever since our ancestors died, everything goes on as it has since the beginning of creation.” 5 But they deliberately forget that long ago by God’s word the heavens came into being and the earth was formed out of water and by water. 6 By these waters also the world of that time was deluged and destroyed. 7 By the same word the present heavens and earth are reserved for **fire**, being kept for the day of judgment and destruction of the ungodly.
>
> 8 But do not forget this one thing, dear friends: With the Lord a day is like a thousand years, and a thousand years are like a day. 9 The Lord is not slow in keeping his promise, as some understand slowness. Instead he is patient with you, not wanting anyone to perish, but everyone to come to repentance.
>
> 10 But the day of the Lord will come like a thief. The heavens will disappear with a roar; the elements will be destroyed by **fire**, and the earth and everything done in it will be laid bare.
>
> 11 Since everything will be destroyed in this way, what kind of people ought you to be? You ought to live holy and godly lives 12 as you look forward to the day of God and speed its coming. That day will bring about the destruction of the heavens by **fire**, and the elements will melt in the heat. 13 But in keeping with his promise we are looking forward to a new heaven and a new earth, where righteousness dwells. - **2 Peter 3:3-13 NIV** (emphasis added)

If we add even the smallest (what we might consider trivial) additions to the text, it becomes very easy to come to a false interpretation - it is strongly adviseable to resist any temptation to do this, but rather to closely examine the text for what it actually *does* say (many people find that praying and asking God's help to do so is extremely beneficial in this process), as well as trying to understand it in the overall context.

Comment: Indeed I am not as studious in the word so I really appreciate the quotes and reply. What is the significance then of the promise? I understand from your quotes the connection between water and fire but it is in the realm of the possibilities something between water and fire. For example: The earth completely frozen by ice symbolizing another connection between god and his children and leading to the fire not yet foretold or read from current text?

Comment: Most Christians (myself included) interpret the promise quite literally - there won't be another global flood that will cover the earth (hard to see how that could happen as well now with the profile of the continents as they are now). Regarding an earth frozen by ice, that is pretty speculative. I think it would be safe to say that most Christians would be pretty surprised if that were to happen before the final judgment - it may cause them to doubt their faith as there doesn't seem to be anything in scripture that would admit that possibility.

Comment: That said, other significant future events may well be hidden from us and discernable from scripture with the benefit of hindsight.

Comment: The Bible implies that despite what many people think today, the Earth was radically different prior to the flood. Today, much of science (particularly geo-sciences) rests on implicit assumptions of gradualism, there are some theories that dabble with catasrophic change, but they are not widely accepted. The passage from Peter can be taken to imply that this tacit assumption is incorrect. What we think of as a 'major event' is highly subjective - often in the immediacy of the moment, we can't really evaluate that - was 9/11 a major event? Was the re-establishment of Israel as a nation?

Comment: From my understanding of things, most (but perhaps not all) Biblical prophecies are geared more towards the relationship of God and his people rather than events that 'the world' are likely to think of as significant.

Comment: I completely agree to what is a major event is relative. It has just been quiet a gap between scripture and present day that there could be major events occurring that are or are not relational to god. I find it neat to think about since it's an ongoing scripture up to judgement day.